# Is there any method like char At in Dart?

Tags: java, dart, methods, charat

```
String name = "Jack";  
char letter = name.charAt(0);    
System.out.println(letter);
```

You know this is a java method **`charAt`** that it gives you a character of a String just by telling the index of the String. I'm asking for a method like this in Dart, does Dart have a method like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.operator[]`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/operator_get.html).

```dart
String name = "Jack";  
String letter = name[0];
print(letter);
```

Note that this operates on UTF-16 *code units*, not on Unicode code points nor on grapheme clusters.  Also note that Dart does not have a `char` type, so you'll end up with another `String`.

If you need to operate on arbitrary Unicode strings, then you should use [`package:characters`](https://pub.dev/packages/characters) and do:

```dart
String name = "Jack";  
Characters letter = name.characters.characterAt(0);
print(letter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Dart has two operations that match the Java behavior, because Java prints integers of the type `char` specially.

Dart has [`String.codeUnitAt`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/String/codeUnitAt.html), which does the same as Java's `charAt`: Returns an integer representing the UTF-16 code unit at that position in the string.
If you print that in Dart, or add it to a `StringBuffer`, it's just an integer, so `print("Jack".codeUnitAt(0))` prints `74`.

The other operations is [`String.operator[]`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/String/operator_get.html), which returns a single-code-unit `String`. So `print("Jack"[0])` prints `J`.

Both should be used very judiciously, since many Unicode characters are not just a single code unit. You can use [`String.runes`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/String/runes.html) to get code *points* or [`String.characters`](https://pub.dev/documentation/characters/latest/characters/StringCharacters/characters.html) from package `characters` to get grapheme clusters (which is usually what you should be using, unless you happen to know text is ASCII only.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
String.substring(int startIndex, [ int endIndex ])
```

Example --

```
void main(){
   String s = "hello";
   print(s.substring(1, 2));
}
```

Output

```
e
```

Note that , endIndex is one greater than startIndex, and the  char which is returned is present at startIndex.